# How do I save my imageView image into Gallery (Android Development)

Tags: android, image, imageview, save, gallery

I am trying to create an onClick event to save an imageview into the phone Gallery by the click of a Button, below is my code. it does not save into the Gallery, can anyone help me figure out why?

```
    sharebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //attempt to save the image

            b = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = b.getDrawingCache();
                //File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                try 
                {
                    cachePath.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: have u given write permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 7):

I do this to save Image in gallery.

```
private void saveImageToGallery(){
    imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = imageview.getDrawingCache();
    Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), b,title, description);
}
```

`insertImage()` will return a `String != null` if image has been really saved.
Also: Needs permission in the manifest as "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
And note that this puts the image at the bottom of the list of images already in the gallery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ANy way you could make it show at the top of the list of images?

Comment: Yes, I use the trick provided by samkirton. [See here](https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9). It works very well

Comment: setDrawingCacheEnabled deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the `ImageView` already keeps the image that you want to save, first, get the Bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Then save it with below code:-

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

And do not forget to set this permission in your manifest:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: do i need to put extension in title ?

Comment: This is by far the best solution I've been able to find, but it looks like it needs to require permission in realtime or it doesn't work. For those seeking a similar method, I'd suggest adding [the code available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39957656/6398434) before implementing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the image to media provider. Here is a simple example:

```
Uri saveMediaEntry(String imagePath,String title,String description,long dateTaken,int orientation,Location loc) {
ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
v.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
v.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, dateTaken);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
v.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateTaken) ;
v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, “image/jpeg”);
v.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, orientation);
File f = new File(imagePath) ;
File parent = f.getParentFile() ;
String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase() ;
String name = parent.getName().toLowerCase() ;
v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
v.put(Images.Media.SIZE,f.length()) ;
f = null ;
if( targ_loc != null ) {
v.put(Images.Media.LATITUDE, loc.getLatitude());
v.put(Images.Media.LONGITUDE, loc.getLongitude());
}
v.put(“_data”,imagePath) ;
ContentResolver c = getContentResolver() ;
return c.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: You've basically copied the code in another person's answer, but have not included any explanation at all about why your answer might work.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery