# Download Bitmap To Gallery Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I generate Qr Code ( Bitmap ) on my app And I want download this to my gallery . How Can I download bitmap ( qr code ) to my gallery .

```
                olustur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Bitmap imageResult = stringToBitmap(texttt.getText().toString());
                        qrcard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        qrcodex.setImageBitmap(imageResult);
                        // I did genarate qr code in there
                    }
                });
            }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i;
        switch (view.getId()) {         
            case R.id.qrindir:
                //I want Download Bitmap in there .
                break;          
    private Bitmap stringToBitmap(String content){
        try {
            QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
            int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
            int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
            return bmp;
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I generate Qr Code with `Bitmap stringToBitmap`

I did set Image to image view with `Bitmap imageResult = stringToBitmap(texttt.getText().toString() ; qrcodex.setImageBitmap(imageResult);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file from bitmap and save it to Gallery:

1. [How to generate file from bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file) - describes how to generate a file from bitmap in memory;
2. For working with Gallery you need to save a photo to external storage. You can read more [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377399/how-do-i-save-my-imageview-image-into-gallery-android-development).